# JS - Search bar does not return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am currently going thru Jonas Schmedtmann's course. As I was going thru a project using ES6, Babel, NPM and WebPack - I stumbled upon an issue. We coded an asynchronous function that returns data from an API, whenever a button in the search bar is clicked it should console.log() the data from server on the given keyword.

However, in my case this is what happens. The API gives you two choices to type into the search bar: "pizza" and "pasta". If I type in something else it (as expected) alerts an error. If, on the other  hand, I type in "pizza" or "pasta" nothing happens. But, it should console.log the data for the specified keyword.

I went through my code multiple times, and everything seems to be alright, no errors in console nor in VSC. I checked tags, files and if my logic's right - nothing. I just can not figure out where the problem lies. Can you help me with this problem?

Down below I will include source codes and directories:

[image]

I named this webpack, because it was my  first time running npm, webpack, babel and simply continued working on the project in this folder. Ignore the folder name.

Here's the code:

**index.js**

```
import Search from './models/search';
import * as searchView from './views/searchView';
import { elements } from './views/base';

/* global sstate of the app
 * - search object
 * - current state of object
 * - shopping list object
 * - liked recipes
 */
const state = {};

const controlSearch = async () => {
    // 1) get query from view
    const query = searchView.getInput(); 
    console.log(query);//TO DO

    if (query) {
        // 2) new search object and add it to state
        state.search = new Search(query);

        // 3) Prepare UI for results

        // 4) Search for recipes

        await state.search.getResults();
        // 5) render results on UI
        console.log(state.search.result);
    }
}

elements.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    controlSearch();
});
```

This is pretty much the core of the app, that imports data from other smaller side files - our instructor wants to make a file for each component of the app separately and then import everything into index.js.

**models/search.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

    export default class Search {
        constructor(query){
        this.query=query;
    }

    async getResults(){
        try{
            const res = await axios(`https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/search?&q=${this.query}`);
            this.result = res.data.recipes;

        }catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    }
}
```

this code pretty much links up to the API and gets the chosen query/data from it.

**views/searchView.js**

```
import { elements } from './base';

export const getInput = () => elements.searchInput.value;
```

**views/base.js**

```
    export const elements = {
    searchForm: document.querySelector('.search'),
    searchInput: document.querySelector('.search__field')
};
```

**index.html**

```
        <form class="search">
            <input type="text" class="search__field" placeholder="Search over 1,000,000 recipes...">
            <button class="btn search__btn">
                <svg class="search__icon">
                    <use href="img/icons.svg#icon-magnifying-glass"></use>
                </svg>
                <span>Search</span>
            </button>
        </form>
```

and, above is the HTML of the search bar

[image]

Lastly, I wanted to show the console after typing in pizza correctly and "pizzzza" purposefully with an error to show how it looks. 
(I could be wrong, but I think those warnings and errors are normal **except** the last one which was a result of requesting an undefined query from the API)

Comment: Why does searching for anything other than pizza or pasta throw an error? Also, your query does not appear in your console logs above, but it should--does `console.log(searchView.getInput())` actually log the value of your input?

Comment: @duhaime pizza and pasta are the only keywords specified in the API. It is a very specific search bar. So the async call seems to work properly. The index.js file holds console.log(query); as well as console.log(state.search.result); which will be later on used to render the UI with recipes. Anyways, I added console.log(searchView.getInput()) as you suggested in index.js after 5) - however, it did not print anything to the console. Do you have any other ideas? This problem is really stopping me from any further action as I won't be able to work on rendering UI elements without fixing this.  :(

Comment: In getResults() method. how do you return the api response data? and where did you declare  this.result = res.data.recipes;  'this.result" variable?

Comment: Hmm, something's disconnected. A few requests and ideas. 1) could you please provide a fully reproducible case? Even a github repo if you must. 2) to get started on UI work, you can "inline" data -- just write `const mydata = []` and replace [] with the JSON you might get for a search. Then you have access to the data and can paint it on the DOM. 3) Are you positive the DOM has rendered when `elements.searchInput.value` is evaluated? It seems you might need to wait to call that line until after the HTML has finished rendering. Make sure your JS is loaded below your HTML...